# How to make JSON Schema recognize a hierarchy of objects?

Tags: json, hierarchy, jsonschema

I'm writing a schema for JSON. Let's say I have an object called "feature". Inside this object there are various properties defined, one of which is "features", which is an array containing another set of "feature". So the hierarchy is virtually infinite.

```
{
  "name": "feature",
  "properties": {
    "feature_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Name of feature",
      "required": true
    },
    "feature_type": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Type of feature",
      "required": true
    },
    "features": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        //How do I define the same object for an infinite hierarchy?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The "features" array could consist of many more "feature" objects, each of which may also have more "features". Can I accommodate for this in a JSON schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not going to be able to implement an infinite hierarchy.  JSON.net seems to be one of the better solutions for this type of problem.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, and .net won't work for me because I'm just using JSON structure for a set of web-based apps written in Delphi.